# Does .NET 6.0 have its own cryptography libs that will enable more secure ciphers than the OS supports?

Tags: .net, windows, cryptography, tls1.2, tls1.3

Does .NET 6.0 have its own libraries that will allow support for later more secure cryptography ciphers for TLS that are not currently support on Windows 2012?

Eg TLS 1.3 or 1.2 with GCM or POLY1305 ciphers

Answer (score 0):

.NET (6) has of course its own libriaries. [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography?view=net-6.0)

Hope that helped you.